# 400番台のエラーが起きたときに意図したリダイレクトが行われない。

Tags: php, cakephp

下記コードを実行(InputController)すると意図したリダイレクトが行われず、
「Missing Method in UsersController
Error: The action index is not defined in controller UsersController」
という表示がされます。
ErrorsControllerのindexアクションにリダイレクトするようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
※phpのバージョン5.4でCakephp2の環境です。

```php
class InputController extends AppController {
    public function index()
    {
        try {
          throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          throw new NotFoundException();
          return;
         }
     }
```

```php
App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function error400($error) {
        $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

```php
class ErrorsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppExceptionRenderer を、有効にしていますか？

AppExceptionRenderer を有効にするには、 `app/Config/core.php` の `Exception.renderer` オプションに `AppExceptionRenderer` をセットします。

app/Config/core.php

```php
    Configure::write('Exception', array(
        'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
        'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer', // <-- ここを書き換え
        'log' => true
    ));
```

参考:
Exception.renderer を使って独自のレンダラを使用し、アプリケーション例外をハンドリングする
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer

Answer (score -1):

「UsersControllerというcontrollerで、indexというアクションが定義されていません」
（その心は：定義してないものを実行しろと言われても、困りますぅ）
というのがエラーの内容なのですから、UsersControllerというcontrollerのプログラムに問題があります。
　ところが、質問に書かれたコードにはUsersControllerのプログラムが含まれていません。

アドバイス
１）　まずは、エラーが発生しているとエラーメッセージが指摘しているUsersControllerに注目しましょう。
　余所見していると無駄に時間を費やすことになりますから。
　修正方法が判らないのであれば、UsersControllerのコードを質問に追加したうえで、困っている点を聞くと回答が得られやすいと思います。

２）　InputControllerのindex関数は、例外を上げるだけのコードになっています。
　どんな用途を想定して作られたのでしょうか？
　400番台のエラーを例外で扱うのなら、try句の中で実行して、catch句で例外を補足して対処（リダイレクトする等）を行うのが素直だと思います。

Comment: 質問の改善を求めるなら質問に対して、コメントすべきと考えます。